# User model inheritance and expanding in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I want to inherit UserProfile class from builtin class User with 2 modifications:

1) username field must be not unique

2) email field must be unique

So, how to override this 2 fields by UserProfile class?

As I understand I can't change class User, so I must do this changes in class UserProfile somehow...
But how to do that???
Help me please!

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just monkey patch.

I've never done this myself, but it was fun digging into this. Check out the model field init function (where we'd need to pass `unique=True`)

```
def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, primary_key=False,
        max_length=None, unique=False, blank=False, null=False,
        db_index=False, rel=None, default=NOT_PROVIDED, editable=True,
        serialize=True, unique_for_date=None, unique_for_month=None,
        unique_for_year=None, choices=None, help_text='', db_column=None,
        db_tablespace=None, auto_created=False, validators=[],
        error_messages=None):
    self.name = name
    self.verbose_name = verbose_name
    self.primary_key = primary_key
    self.max_length, self._unique = max_length, unique
```

All it seems to care about is that an attribute `_unique` is True or False. The rest of django magic shouldn't care how that attribute was set, so let's monkey patch!

Put a monkey patch app somewhere in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, and put this in your `models.py` (which is auto loaded):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User._meta.get_field("username")._unique = False
User._meta.get_field("email")._unique = True
```

Sure enough, django generates the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "auth_user" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "username" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "first_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "last_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "email" varchar(75) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "password" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    "is_staff" bool NOT NULL,
    "is_active" bool NOT NULL,
    "is_superuser" bool NOT NULL,
    "last_login" datetime NOT NULL,
    "date_joined" datetime NOT NULL
)
```